# tastypie with django-simple-history - display model history as rest API

Tags: django, model, history, tastypie

I would like to share django model history (created by [django-simple-history](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history)) using tastypie. 
Problem is, how to prepare `ModelResource` for this purpose.

Access to model history is by `model.history` manager. So access to all changes of model we can gain by `model.history.all()`

What i would like to obtain? For example. I have django model `Task` and the API endpoints:

1. `http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/task` - display all tasks list
2. `http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/task/1` - display details for choosen task
3. `http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/task/1/history` - display history of task no. 1

First two *links* presents default behavior of `ModelResource`. what i have till now?

```
class TaskResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        # it displays all available history entries for all task objects
        queryset = Task.history.all() 
        resource_name = 'task'

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/history$" % (self._meta.resource_name,),
                self.wrap_view('get_history'),
                name="api_history"),
            ]

    def get_history(self, request, **kwargs):
        #...
```

`get_history` should return bundle with history entries.. but how this method should look?
I guess, i need to create bundle with needed data, but don't know how exactly should i do that.
Does someeone have experience with simple-history and tastypie to present some simple example?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, solution was simpler than i thought. Maybe someone use this in feature:

```
class TaskHistoryResource(ModelResource):
   class Meta:
     queryset = Task.history.all()
     filtering = { 'id' = ALL }

class TaskResource(ModelResource):
   history = fields.ToManyField(AssetTypeHistoryResource, 'history')

   class Meta:
     # it displays all available history entries for all task objects
     queryset = Task.history.all() 
     resource_name = 'task'

   def prepend_urls(self):
     return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/history$" %(self._meta.resource_name,),
            self.wrap_view('get_history'),
            name="api_history"),
        ]

    def get_history(self, request, **kwargs):
      try:
         bundle = self.build_bundle(data={'pk': kwargs['pk']}, request=request)
         obj = self.cached_obj_get(bundle=bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
      except ObjectDoesNotExist:
         return HttpGone()
      except MultipleObjectsReturned:
         return HttpMultipleChoices("More than one resource is found at this URI.")

      history_resource = TaskHistoryResource()
      return history_resource.get_list(request, id=obj.pk)
```

A bit changed solution from:
http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#nested-resources

Basically, there was need to create additional resource with history entries. `get_history` method creates and returns instance of it with appropriate filter on `id` field (in [django-simple-history](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history) `id` field contain `id` of major object. Revision primary key names `history_id`)

Hope, that will help someone.